# $A=I_9-2u^Tu$ with $u=\frac{1}{3}[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]$. If $p$ and $q$ are two distinct eigen values of $A$ then ,$|p-q|$ is

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

consider the matrix $A=I_9-2u^Tu$ with $u=\frac{1}{3}[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]$.  If $p$ and $q$ are two distinct eigen values of $A$ then ,$|p-q|$ is ______

I tried to solve the equation $A=I_9-2u^Tu$ but I get the $9 \times 9$ matrix and I am  not able to proceed further ...Can anyone please help me..Thanks in advance

Comment: Hints: If $Mv=\lambda v$, then what does $(I-M)v$ equal? What is the dimension of the image (column space) of $2u^Tu$?

Comment: the dimension is 81??

Comment: Do you even know what the column space of a matrix is?

Comment: Yeah it is 9...

Comment: No, it's not nine. Do you know what $u^tu$ looks like?

Comment: $u^Tu$ is $9\times 9$ matrix

Answer (score 1):

This matrix can be geometrically interpreted as the reflection operator with respect to the hyperplane orthogonal to the **unit** vector $u$ (see [there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics)),  paragraph "Reflection through a hyperplane in n dimensions").

The eigenvalues of such an operator are

$$-1 \ (\text{multiplicity} \ 1), \ \ \ 1 (\text{multiplicity} \ 8) \tag{1}$$

resp. associated with eigenvectors $u$ and $v_k \ (k=1 \cdots 8)$, where the $v_k$s constitute a basis of the hyperplane. Indeed $Au=(-1)u$ and $Av_k=(1)v_k$ ($u$ is "mirrored" into its opposite vector, whereas the $v_k$s are "mirrored" into themselves).

Therefore, an immediate consequence of (1) is that the answer to your question is

> $|p-q|$ can only take the value $2$.