# Let $T:\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C^n$ be a linear operator of rank $n-2$ then,

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T:\mathbb C^n\to \mathbb C^n$ be a linear operator of rank $n-2$ then,

1. $0$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$.
2. $0$ is must be an eigenvalue of $T$.
3. $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $T$.
4. $1$ is must be an eigenvalue of $T$.

I tried and I found its nullity is $n+2$ and I am not able to proceed further.

Comment: The nullity can't be greater than $n$, the dimension of the domain. Why do you think it is $n+2$?

Comment: here the dimension is 2n

Comment: Well, what is $C^n$ to begin with and what is the underlying field in this question?

Comment: @Christoph he must be thinking over $\Bbb R$.

Comment: Linear operators $\Bbb C^n\to \Bbb C^n$ is much more constricted than linear operators $\Bbb R^{2n}\to\Bbb R^{2n}$. For instance, if $n = 1$, then linear operators $\Bbb C\to \Bbb C$ are just (complex) scalar multiplications, while linear operators $\Bbb R^2\to \Bbb R^2$ can do much more, like mirroring, shearing, or collapsing one dimension.

Comment: You can still have $\mathbb R$-linear maps $\mathbb C^n\to\mathbb C^n$. If that is the case in this question, it should be expressed clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming the underlying field is $\mathbb C$. If $0$ is not an eigen value then $T$ is invertible and its rank is $n$. Hence 2) is true and 1) is false. It is easy to find examples where $1$ is an eigen value and examples where $1$ is not an eigen value: just look at diagonal matrices.

Comment: Sir can you give examples for option 3 and 4

Comment: Diagonal matrix with diagonal entries entries $(0,0,3,...,n)$ and diagonal matrix with diagonal entries entries $(0,0,1,4,...,n)$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3261793/a-i-9-2utu-with-u-frac131-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-1-if-p-and-q-ar

Comment: Sir can you please tell m the answer for this question

Answer (score 1):

I think that $C= \mathbb C.$

We have $n=\dim (ker(T))+rank(T)=\dim (ker(T))+n-2$, hence $\dim (ker(T))=2.$

This shows that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $T$.

For 3. and 4. let $n=3$ and consider

$T_1= diag(1,0,0)$ and $T_2= diag(2,0,0).$

Answer (score 0):

Since you appear to be considering $\Bbb C^n$ over $\Bbb R$, I believe that since you correctly noted the nullity, $0$ must be an eigenvalue.   That is,  the kernel is nontrivial.